# Would an avel who visits the Kotel need to do an extra tearing?

Tags: mourning-aveilus, kotel-western-wall

In the back of a siddur, I saw one of the *halachot* state that one who has not visited the *Kotel* ("Western Wall" in Jerusalem) within 30 days should tear his clothes when he comes to the *Kotel*.

Let's say an *avel* (mourner) can't get a minyan in his home. He goes to the *Kotel* to pray with a minyan, there. An *avel* would already be wearing torn clothes during his week of *shiva*. If he goes to the *Kotel* would he need to tear again (same shirt, or perhaps wear a different shirt), or is the torn shirt that he is already wearing for his own *aveilut* sufficient?

Comment: I haven't found anything on point yet, but M"K 26a gives 2 examples of double kriah -- in those cases, the two concepts re related and one might think that one kriah could cover both. In your case, maybe one could say kal vachomer, when there is no such hava amina, then certainly 2 tears. But that's just an off the cuff theory on my part.

Comment: Just to clarify - the obligation of kriyah is not specifically connected to the Western Wall (see e.g. http://hirhurim.blogspot.com/2010/05/kriah-at-kotel.html )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wearing torn clothing isn't the command. A tear for one event doesn't help at all for another later event. Even if another relative passes away during Shiva he would need to tear again (YD 340:21-23; see there for details about when one can add on to an existing tear and when one tear can count for two simultaneous events).